# Is there a way to have customised text instead of subject in Thunderbird's inbox list?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I am getting a lot of informational emails like "You've got a new message from ..." or "Notification of Donation Received", which often do not contain any information in the subject so that I have to open the email to see who sent the message or who donated which amount.

I'd love to be able to make TB parse incoming emails and then display something interesting instead of the original subject, e.g. by defining a regular expression pattern.

I know how to write regular expressions, but I do not know whether there is a way or an addon to modify the displayed text in the messages view.

**EDIT** for clarification: I would like donation notifications from Paypal not to be displayed as original

> Notification of Donation Received

but rather

> Paypal: John Doe has donated 50$

Answer (score 2):

https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla

That's no simple solution, but it allows:

- to append (or prepend) text to subject
- to filter messages using JavaScript, and apply JavaScripts actions to messages

Documentation available at http://mesquilla.com/extensions/filtaquilla/, with examples.

Quote:

```
As a trivial example, to prepend the text “[Hello world]” to the front of each messages’s subject, use the following javascript:
for (let index = 0; index < msgHdrs.length; index++)
{
  let hdr = msgHdrs.queryElementAt(index, Ci.nsIMsgDBHdr);
  hdr.subject = "[Hello, world] " + hdr.subject;
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing me to this useful plugin. Unfortunately, for my task I'd need "Javascript Action with Body" which is declared an "experimental" feature and not really documented :( I am neither afraid of Javascript nor Regex, but it is painful to figure out the data structure, even more as the programming is done in a text input field. What a pity - apart from that it seems to be exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @peterp there are more examples: http://paperlined.org/apps/thunderbird/FiltaQuilla/examples.html . Also, according to [screenshot](http://mesquilla.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/RemoteContentPolicy2.jpg) \(from [here](http://mesquilla.com/2010/05/20/javascript-custom-filter-action-in-new-filtaquilla/)\), there must be multiline way to edit script.